How to create mutually dependent checkbox columns in a DT table?
I try to create the included and excluded checkbox in DT table.
If the user selects included TRUE, then excluded will auto update FALSE.
If the user selects included FALSE, then excluded will auto update TRUE.
It can be FALSE for both but NOT TRUE for both, I couldn't find any solution here
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x1'),
    verbatimTextOutput('x2')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, value, ...) {
      if (length(value) == 1) value <- rep(value, len)
      inputs = character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, value = value[i]))
      }
      inputs
    }
    
    # obtain the values of inputs
    shinyValue = function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) TRUE else value
      }))
    }

    
    
    n = 6
    df = data.frame(
      included = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'in_', value = TRUE, width='1px'),
      excluded = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'ex_', value = FALSE, width='1px'),
      ID = seq_len(n),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    loopData = reactive({
      df$included  <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'in_', value = shinyValue('in_', n), width='1px')
      df$excluded <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'ex_', value = FALSE, width='1px')
      df
    })
    
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      isolate(loopData()),
      escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      ))
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
    
    observe({
      replaceData(proxy, loopData(), resetPaging = FALSE)
    })
    
    output$x2 = renderPrint({
      data.frame(Inclusion = shinyValue('in_', n),
                 Exclusion = shinyValue('ex_', n))
    })
  }
)





"If the user selects included FALSE, then excluded will auto update TRUE.": In this case it would not be possible to have "It can be FALSE for both" I think, because, when included is set to FALSE, excluded will automatically updated to be TRUE. Is this okay for you? If so, I can provide an answer (where it is implemented that always exact one box is checked in every row). Or shall "If the user selects included FALSE, then excluded will auto update TRUE." not work in the opposite direction?

I think it's fine, please provide an answer, it will help me a lot. Thanks

You can define a reactiveVal which keeps track of the current checkbox values (here checkboxValues). Additionally, we generate several  observeEvent using lapply which get triggered if one of the inputs is changed. And then we change the respective other inputs such that two checkboxes never have the same value. This would look like this for the included column as the trigger:
lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("in_", x)]], {
        ins <- shinyValue('in_', n)
        exs <- shinyValue('ex_', n)
        checkBoxValues(data.frame(ins = ins, exs = !ins))
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })


You can modify the behavior of the update of checkBoxValues if you would like to allow other combinations.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x1'),
    verbatimTextOutput('x2')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, value, ...) {
      if (length(value) == 1) value <- rep(value, len)
      inputs = character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, value = value[i]))
      }
      inputs
    }
    
    # obtain the values of inputs
    shinyValue = function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) TRUE else value
      }))
    }
    
    n = 6
    df = data.frame(
      included = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'in_', value = TRUE, width='1px'),
      excluded = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'ex_', value = FALSE, width='1px'),
      ID = seq_len(n),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    checkBoxValues <- reactiveVal(
      data.frame(ins = rep(TRUE, n), exs = rep(FALSE, n))
    )
    
    loopData = reactive({
      df$included <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'in_', value = checkBoxValues()$ins, width='1px')
      df$excluded <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'ex_', value = checkBoxValues()$exs, width='1px')
      df
    })
    
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      isolate(loopData()),
      escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      ))
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
    
    observe({
      replaceData(proxy, loopData(), resetPaging = FALSE)
    })
    
    lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("in_", x)]], {
        ins <- shinyValue('in_', n)
        exs <- shinyValue('ex_', n)
        checkBoxValues(data.frame(ins = ins, exs = !ins))
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
    
    lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("ex_", x)]], {
        exs <- shinyValue('ex_', n)
        checkBoxValues(data.frame(ins = !exs, exs = exs))
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
    
    output$x2 = renderPrint({
      data.frame(Inclusion = shinyValue('in_', n),
                 Exclusion = shinyValue('ex_', n))
    })
  }
)



I try to add another column "not filter", I couldn't make it work, just only 1 column selected. Can you help me take a look?

Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79188930/follow-up-how-to-create-mutually-dependent-checkbox-columns-in-a-dt-table
