How to dynamically update column values depending on a checkboxInput state?
I follow this question Register shiny checkboxInput value on DT, but I couldn't figure out how to use text "Included" for TRUE and "Excluded" for FALSE in column value.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "$('[id^=check]').on('click', function(){",
  "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
  "  var i = parseInt(/check(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
  "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
  "  var cell = table.cell(i-1, 2).data(value).draw();",
  "})"
)

df <- data.frame(item = c("a", "b", "c"), value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
  }
  inputs
}

## obtaining checkbox value
shinyValue = function(id, len) { 
  unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) { 
    value = input[[paste0(id, i)]] 
    if (is.null(value)) FALSE else value 
  })) 
} 

shinyCheckboxes <- function(len, id, checked){
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(checkboxInput(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, 
                                            value = checked[i]))
  }
  inputs
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
  output$tbl <- renderDT(server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, editable = TRUE, 
                         callback = JS(js),
                         options = list(
                           dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                           preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                         ), {
                           checked <- sapply(df$value, isTRUE)
                           df$value_check <- shinyCheckboxes(nrow(df), "check", checked)
                           #df$value_check <- shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(df), "check")
                           df
                         }
  )
  
  
  observeEvent(input$tbl_rows_selected,{
    print(input$tbl_rows_selected)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("tbl")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)


Desired output:
How we can use "Included" for TRUE and "Excluded" for FALSE in column value?

Within the callback, change var value = $(this).prop('checked'); to var value = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'Included': 'Excluded';. This notation uses the Conditional (ternary) operator and means that if the box is checked, then use 'Included', otherwise 'Excluded'.
What you additionally need is to have this in the initialized table. Below I set this by directly defining 'Included' as the start value of the column (previously TRUE) and changing the checked column definition to checked <- sapply(df$value, \(x) x == "Included").

library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "$('[id^=check]').on('click', function(){",
  "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
  "  var i = parseInt(/check(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
  "  var value = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'Included': 'Excluded';",
  "  var cell = table.cell(i-1, 2).data(value).draw();",
  "})"
)

df <- data.frame(item = c("a", "b", "c"), value = rep('Included', 3))

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
  }
  inputs
}

## obtaining checkbox value
shinyValue = function(id, len) { 
  unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) { 
    value = input[[paste0(id, i)]] 
    if (is.null(value)) FALSE else value 
  })) 
} 

shinyCheckboxes <- function(len, id, checked){
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(checkboxInput(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, 
                                            value = checked[i]))
  }
  inputs
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$tbl <- renderDT(server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, editable = TRUE, 
                         callback = JS(js),
                         options = list(
                           dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                           preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                         ), {
                           checked <- sapply(df$value, \(x) x == "Included")
                           df$value_check <- shinyCheckboxes(nrow(df), "check", checked)
                           #df$value_check <- shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(df), "check")
                           df
                         }
  )
  
  
  observeEvent(input$tbl_rows_selected,{
    print(input$tbl_rows_selected)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("tbl")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)


I have a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79062059/create-2-checkbox-columns-in-dt-table-with-conditions-in-r-shiny. Can you please help me take a look? @Jan
