How to create multiple mutually dependent checkbox columns in a DT table?
@Ben helped me created a DT table with 2 columns, which one of them should be TRUE, now I need to add another column, but it doesn't work.
If the user selects included TRUE, then excluded and filter will auto update FALSE. If the user selects included FALSE, then excluded and filter will auto update TRUE.
It can be FALSE for all but NOT TRUE for all, I couldn't find any solution here.
Anyone can help me?
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('x1'),
    verbatimTextOutput('x2')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # create a character vector of shiny inputs
    shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, value, ...) {
      if (length(value) == 1) value <- rep(value, len)
      inputs = character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, value = value[i]))
      }
      inputs
    }
    
    # obtain the values of inputs
    shinyValue = function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
        if (is.null(value)) TRUE else value
      }))
    }
    
    n = 6
    df = data.frame(
      included = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'in_', value = TRUE, width='1px'),
      excluded = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'ex_', value = FALSE, width='1px'),
      Not_filter = shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'filter_', value = FALSE, width='1px'),
      ID = seq_len(n),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    checkBoxValues <- reactiveVal(
      data.frame(ins = rep(TRUE, n), exs = rep(FALSE, n),filters = rep(FALSE, n))
    )
    
    loopData = reactive({
      df$included <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'in_', value = checkBoxValues()$ins, width='1px')
      df$excluded <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'ex_', value = checkBoxValues()$exs, width='1px')
      df$Not_filter <<- shinyInput(checkboxInput, n, 'filter_', value = checkBoxValues()$filters, width='1px')
      df
    })
    
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      isolate(loopData()),
      escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
      options = list(
        dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
      ))
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
    
    observe({
      replaceData(proxy, loopData(), resetPaging = FALSE)
    })
    
    lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("in_", x)]], {
        ins <- shinyValue('in_', n)
        exs <- shinyValue('ex_', n)
        filter <- shinyValue('filter_', n)
        checkBoxValues(data.frame(ins = ins, exs = !ins, filter = !ins))
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
    
    lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("filter_", x)]], {
        filter <- shinyValue('filter_', n)
        exs <- shinyValue('ex_', n)
        checkBoxValues(data.frame(ins = !filter, exs = !filter, filter = filter))
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })

    lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("ex_", x)]], {
        exs <- shinyValue('ex_', n)
        checkBoxValues(data.frame(ins = !exs, exs = exs, filter = !exs))
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
    
    output$x2 = renderPrint({
      data.frame(Inclusion = shinyValue('in_', n),
                 Exclusion = shinyValue('ex_', n),
                 NotFiter = shinyValue('filter_', n))
    })
  }
)


The one major issue with your current approach is that you have a typo, in checkBoxValues, you define filters = rep(FALSE, n) and later you update checkBoxValues by e.g. using filter = !ins ("s" missing). The other thing is that if you correct that, you may get circular dependencies where the updates of the input trigger each other which has to be avoided.

@Jan I fixed it but the logic is not working

You should provide an updated minimal example which is not working.

Look at this answer in S.O. R Shiny, how to make datatable react to checkboxes in datatable
